If $n^2/4 - 2l^2/k^2$ is an integer then $k^2 = 4$.
I was reading some lecture notes for a course on algebraic number theory and I came across the statement in the title. That is, we have that $\frac{n^2}{4} - \frac{2l^2}{k^2}$ is an integer, where $n,k,l$ are all integers. The author then says "Since this is an integer, we deduce that we can take $k^2 = 4$, or $k = 2$. But I don't quite follow. Maybe I'm missing something trivial?

might as well demand $\gcd(l,k)=1.$   Then multiply through by $4,$   this must also be an integer; subtract the $n^2$ and so on

So that gives $n^2 - 4m = \frac{8l^2}{k^2}$. Is that what you were implying?

@WillJagy: Your "might as well demand" is misleading. The statement is patently false unless we demand that $\gcd(l,k)=1$. The author should have said (or perhaps already said) that $\gcd(l,k)$ is assumed to be $1$.

azu, So $\gcd(l,k)=1$ and $8 l^2 = t k^2 $  for some integer $t.$  And $\gcd(l^2,k^2) = 1.$  Then what happens?

Ah so $k^2 \mid 8l^2$ and since $\gcd(k^2,l^2) = 1$, we have $k^2 \mid 8$ which is only possible if $k^2 = 4$. Thanks.
